# BNFC install error

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci, bnfc

I am trying to install BNFC on my Mac (Running OS Sierra). I have already installed the Haskell Platform for Mac (v.8.0.1)
I have installed cabal then used that to install alex (v 3.2.1) and happy (v 1.19.5). I then ran the cabal install bnfc and that installs properly. The problem is as soon as I type bnfc or try using any bnfc commands I get:

> *-bash: bnfc: command not found*

Is there something I am missing here? 
When I try installing BNFC again I get:

> *All the requested packages are already installed: BNFC-2.8.1*

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up copying across the files (alex, bnfc and happy) from

> /Users/*username*/Library/Haskell/bin

to

> /usr/local/bin/

and all working now

Answer (score 2):

The Haskell Platform should already come with alex and happy. cabal installs binaries to `~/.cabal/bin` by default, which may not be on your `PATH`.

Comment: How do I go about adding that to my PATH?

Comment: Depends on the shell you use. For bash, you'd normally add a line such as `export PATH="~/.cabal/bin:$PATH"` to the end of your `.bashrc`.